# Is IIS Advanced Logging faster than ODBC logging?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, logging, iis-7.5

I believe ODBC logging is slowing my website down.  I read that IIS Advanced Logging can give me what I need with the Log Parser (I think).

Is the Advanced Logging worth the time to implement?

Will it be a **lot** faster than ODBC logging?

Is LogParser the same as IIS Advanced Logging?

edit:  can anyone tell me why I'd want to use this, http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2007/05/01/building-an-iis7-sql-logging-module-with-net.aspx instead of the built in ODBC logging?  What I have now puts every single item in the log.  If someone gets a graphic on the page it goes in the log, for example.  That's too much.

I want to see the query string and the like, but I don't care that icon/image x was downloaded on the page.

Comment: It all depends on what you're logging to. If you set up ODBC logging to an MS Access database stored on an 18-drive 3.5" floppy disk array, then yes you should change it. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xk_XaJ7gE4Q

Comment: It is to Sql Server Express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not log directly to a database, it's a really bad idea.  Microsoft is fairly specific with this.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245243

"Microsoft does not recommend IIS logging to a SQL Server table if the IIS computer is a busy server. Sending logging data to a SQL Server database for a busy Web site consumes system resources."

It's fairly simple to setup a custom log importer that bulk inserts the log data after the fact.  If your goal is just to get the logs into a SQL database, the IIS Advanced Logging would probably be overkill.

Comment: What do you mean bulk inserts after the fact?  Do you mean I do logging in another format and then the custom importer later puts that into SQL Server?

Comment: No - after the IIS log file is created and a new log file is started, the previous IIS log is a candidate for import in to the SQL database.  This can be done with SQL command line tools such as bcp.exe, or you can have your own custom managed code that does essentially the same thing.